# Jquery Second On/Off

Tags: jquery, settimeout, delay

I use jQuery. What I want to do is click on the img element and put the function in a passive state. After 2 seconds, the click function is activated. I used Delay and SetTimeout, but did not. Could you help?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Almost sounds like throttle/debounce logic.

Comment: the first method I tried   $("#menubar").click(function () {
                                     $(this).off("click");
                                     $(this).delay(2000).on("click");
                                       });

Comment: Can you explain what you mean exactly when you say "passive state" in regards to if the user click the image multiple times within the two second window?

Comment: img will be clicked. The clicking event will become inactive and will become active after 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

if you use `setTimeout()` correctly it has to work :

```js
  $("#thatImg").click(
    function() {
        console.log("clicked now");

        setTimeout(
            function() {
                alert("function after delay");
            },
            2000);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="thatImg" alt="Click Me"/>
```

Comment: Alert tried to work. İmg did not work in active passive case.

Answer (score 0):

I have try 2. method;

```
$("#menubar").on('click', clickEvent);
        function doit() {
            $("#menubar").on();
            setTimeout(
                function () {
                    $("#menubar").on('click', clickEvent);
                },
                5000);
        }
        function clickEvent() {
            $("#menubar").off('click');
            doit();
        }
```

Comment: You should have included that attempt in your question instead of in an answer...